# InfluxDB 2.0 unexpected token trying to group by time

Tags: influxdb, influxql, influxdb-2

So I have data in a bucket in InfluxDB 2.0
I'm in the "Data Explorer" and I'm trying to write a query to see the data that I have inserted.

I'm trying a simple query, but I can't seem to make it work, even if I took an example from the documentation.

```
SELECT COUNT(driverNo) FROM "csvDataTest" WHERE time >= "2021-01-18T00:06:00Z" AND time < "2021-08-18T00:18:00Z" GROUP BY time(12m,6m)
```

It keeps saying

```
unexpected token for property key: DURATION (12m)
```

All examples I've seen in the documentation group by time this way.

What am I doing wrong? Can anyone help me?

[image: screen error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I think I have figured it out. I think I was looking at the documentation from version 1.7 instead of version 2.0

It works when I try the syntax from the 2.0 documentation.

https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/query-data/flux/group-data/

The query looks something like this instead (I removed the count, still working on query syntax but the group by clause works now).

```
from(bucket: "csvDataTest")
|> range(start: 1900-01-10T00:00:00Z, stop: 2021-04-23T00:00:00Z)
|> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "channels")
|> filter(fn: (r) => r.driverNo == "12345")
|> group(columns: ["_time"])
```